# Something is wrong when i get the text value with .innerHTML but the mistake says that is not node type?

Tags: javascript

```js
var EditarTarea = function TheEditionOfHomework(Q) {
  //Aqui Tenemos Los Nuev_li Seleccionados

  //.ActionElements are li Elements , .Nuev_a is a element and .ContentElement is a p element that contain the text value that i want to replace with the next prompt below

  var LosHijitosDeApa = List.querySelectorAll(".ActionElements .Nuev_a .Content"),

    //Cantidad De Los Nuev_li Seleccionados , nuember of all the found elements in the body
    lengeted = LosHijitosDeApa.length;

  //Recorrer Todos Los Nuev_li , Sus Nuev_a & Su Content Dentro De Cada Uno , run trought all the found elements the function

  for (var Q = lengeted - 1; Q >= 0; Q--){
    //The goal of this is get the content text value that is inside a Nuev_a Element , this is inside li Nuev_li Element,And this is inside the li List Element

    var LittleEditFuncion = function LittEddit(){
      var Selected = LosHijitosDeApa[Q].innerHTML;

      //Customized question of change the specific element that refer in the selection.

      var LaSustitucion = prompt("Change The Name : " + "(" + Selected + ")" + " With the text that you going to write in this prompt");

      //The goal is to replace the text paragraph with the text that we get with the prompt , in othr case i try with :/*LosHijitosDeApa[Q].children.replaceChild(LaSustitucion, Selected);*/
      //but it arrive the same mistake

      LosHijitosDeApa[Q].replaceChild(LaSustitucion, Selected);

      /*Selected = Selected.replace(LaSustitucion);*/
      /*LosHijitosDeApa[Q].replaceWith(LaSustitucion);*/
    }
    LittleEditFuncion();
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you debug code when it's so appallingly formatted?

Comment: in `.replaceChild(LaSustitucion, Selected);` ...  `LaSustitucion` and `Selected` need to be a NODE not a string - try `LosHijitosDeApa[Q].innerHTML = LaSustitucion` instead, chief

Comment: You have same name variable `Q` as argument and in loop. So arg value will be replaced

Comment: The question should be in the body, not the title. You need to report the errors you get and provide a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks so much , i only try it with text nodes but i never know that function only work with Nodes.

Comment: Yeha it works but it not replace the text value , intead it says : items hidden by filters